# Why is Mongoose only saving part of the data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, save

I've been saving/retrieving data from MongoDB successfully within this app until today.  Now, I go to save, and as far as I can tell, only part of the information gets saved.  Also, I expected the saving to happen on the `await gameData.save()` line, but it appears to happen after my second query.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the troublesome code:

```
var gameData = await GameData.findById(req.params.id);
var selectedIndex = req.params.selectedIndex;

console.log("====================");
console.log("Before:");
console.log(`Money: ${gameData.players[gameData.activePlayer].money}`);
console.log(`Bets: ${gameData.players[gameData.activePlayer].bets}`);
if(gameData.players[gameData.activePlayer].money > 0) {
    gameData.players[gameData.activePlayer].money--;
    gameData.players[gameData.activePlayer].bets[selectedIndex]++;
}
console.log("After:");
console.log(`Money: ${gameData.players[gameData.activePlayer].money}`);
console.log(`Bets: ${gameData.players[gameData.activePlayer].bets}`);

await gameData.save(function(err){
    if(err){
         console.log(err);
         return;
    }
    console.log("Saved successfully!");
});

var verify = await GameData.findById(req.params.id);
console.log("Should be the same as 'After':");
console.log(`Money: ${verify.players[gameData.activePlayer].money}`);
console.log(`Bets: ${verify.players[gameData.activePlayer].bets}`);
```

And here is my Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const opts = { toJSON: { virtuals: true } };

const GameData = new Schema({
    currentDeck: [],
    bank: Number,
    activePlayer: Number,
    spellingPlayer: Number,
    researchLine: [],
    discard: [],
    currentWord: [],
    currentWordReference: [],
    submitionIsAWord: Boolean,
    players: [
        {
            hand: [],
            money: Number,
            bets: [],
            user: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        }
    ]
}, opts);

GameData.virtual('allBets').get(function () {
    var allBets = [0,0,0,0,0];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        allBets[i] = this.players[0].bets[i] + this.players[1].bets[i] + this.players[2].bets[i] + this.players[3].bets[i];
    }
    return allBets;
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('gameData', GameData);
```

And here is the console from the troublesome code:

```
====================
Before:
Money: 8
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0
After:
Money: 7
Bets: 1,0,0,0,0
Should be the same as 'After':
Money: 8
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0
Saved successfully!
====================
Before:
Money: 7
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0
After:
Money: 6
Bets: 1,0,0,0,0
Should be the same as 'After':
Money: 7
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0
Saved successfully!
```

Comment: Using await while passing a callback feels odd, does it work the way you expect if you verify inside the callback?

Comment: @Joe Normally it's just object.save(), but that doesn't work either.  If I verify inside the callback, the "Saved successfully!" it shows up when I expect, but the Bets information isn't saved.
This is the new console output:
`====================
Before:
Money: 6
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0
After:
Money: 5
Bets: 1,0,0,0,0
Saved successfully!
Should be the same as 'After':
Money: 5
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0
====================
Before:
Money: 5
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0
After:
Money: 4
Bets: 1,0,0,0,0
Saved successfully!
Should be the same as 'After':
Money: 4
Bets: 0,0,0,0,0`

Comment: I noticed that trying to edit a player's hand array also results in the same problem.  Perhaps I can only effectively save data that isn't nested so deep?  I'm not sure.